# In IntelliJ is there an easier way to set up the "Complete Current Statement" like eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have used Eclipse for Java for the last few years and am trying out Intellij. I'm not using it permanently because it isn't as useful for quick programming (like how you can't just drag in files into the src folder) but for doing certain things, I think it will be faster for me.

I know there is Ctrl+Shift+Enter, but this is just annoying to press. Not because it is awkward to press, but because it takes so much time compared to just pressing enter like you can in Eclipse. I tried to rebind it to enter, but then it just doesn't work.

Is there a way to set up the Complete Current Statement so that it happens when I press enter?

Like, is there a way that I can bind it to Enter, but have it checked before the editor checks for enter as move to next line?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only basic Code completion and not Type completion, use Ctrl+Space

Comment: Well I am fine with what Ctrl+Shift+Enter does, but I just hate the shortcut, it takes too long to press

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ and Android Studio are pretty highly customisable. You can rebind shortcuts too, I believe. Have you looked here? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Also cheatsheet might be of use: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

And Android specific bindings: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html

Comment: Yeah I read over all of those, it is just the keybinding that I don't like, I'm just wondering if I can properly bind the shortcut to simply "Enter" and still have it work